# Does jQuery .load() load the entire page when used with an element by its id?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a page which is composed by a nav-bar, a side-bar and the main page. Also, I have a jQuery code that apply a load() method to a element from the navbar by its ID. I though that it only reload this element, but what I'm seeing is that a xhl request is being done, calling the entire Index method of my Rails app.

Is this the correct and normal behavior of the load() method over a single element or I'm missing something? Because I don't want to reload (despite is not a real refresh of the page) all the content in order to avoid the re-calling to the Index method in Rails.

Comment: No. The load method applied to an element will set the element innerHTML property with the data received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the load method (having signature ***.load(url [, data ] [, complete ])*** ) will not reload your page but will use *XMLHTTPRequest* to get the data.

The [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/) explains it well:

> load data from the server and place the returned HTML into the matched element. (…) This method is the simplest way to fetch data from the server. It is roughly equivalent to **$.get(url, data, success)**